# Catching error when dividing by 0 in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, calculator, divide-by-zero

So i am making calculator app in swift and i want to display "Error" instead default "Inf" message on the UIlabel when user tries to divide any number by zero
Here is my code but it does not displays my "error" message
any ideas what should i do?

```
switch operationActive
            {
                case 1001:
                    x = y + x
                case 1002:
                    x = y - x
                case 1003:
                    x = y * x
                case 1004:
                    x = y / x
                    if x == 0
                    {
                        self.result.text = "Error"
                }
                //Default is our "=" sign
                default: self.result.text = " " + String(x)
        }
```

Here is the full non-working version

```
 @IBAction func operations(sender: UIButton)
    {
        if enterFlag != 1 && yFlag == 1
        {
            switch operationActive
            {
                case 1001:
                    x = y + x
                case 1002:
                    x = y - x
                case 1003:
                    x = y * x
                case 1004:
                    if x == 0
                    {
                        self.result.text = "Error"
                }
                    else {
                        x = y / x
                }
                //Default is our "=" sign
                default: self.result.text = " " + String(x)
        }
        }
```

Comment: You could switch the order of the statements and add an else clause.

Comment: tried that, not working (

Comment: [Error Handling in Swift](http://nsscreencast.com/episodes/142-error-handling-in-swift)

Answer (score 2):

You need to guard divide by zero first, just switch the order.

```
if x == 0 {
    self.result.text = "Error"
} else {
    x = y / x
}
```

And I guess `x` and `y` are not `Int`, so the condition should be

```
if abs(x - 0) < 0.0000001 {
    self.result.text = "Error"
}
```

Comment: so i added print("error by zero detected") it showed up, meaning that self.result.text = "Error" not working now

Comment: might be some parts in your code are messing with `self.result.text`

Comment: There is no floating point error with the number zero, therefore you can also just check for `x == 0`. Also you'd have to use `abs(x-0)` anyways or it wouldn't work with negative numbers

Comment: Thanks, I forgot negative case.

Comment: There still is no floating point error with the value `0`, just replace `abs(x-0) < 0.0001` with `x == 0` for the function to behave correctly